# Get Params Hash with values as nested arrays - Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, erb, parameters

I would like to get params from the new template for create action in nested array format.
Eg. I am trying to build an excel kind of form.
So I have 3 main headings Feelings, Questions, Events
Feelings and Events have 5 columns each and Events has 1 column
I get all events data in an array of 5 hash elements
I want to get feelings and questions data as an nested array of 5 hash elements
So Event = [{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}]
Would want feelings and questions to be 
[[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}],[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}],[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}],[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}],[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}]]

Currently get the stuff as array of hashes
[{"0"=>[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}]},{"1"=>[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}] ...]

```
<tr>
<th class="col1" colspan="5"><%= label_tag('feelings') %></th>
<th class="col2" colspan="5"><%= label_tag('questions') %></th>
<th class="col3" colspan="1"><%= label_tag('events') %></th>
</tr>
<% @objects[:events].count.times do |count| %>
<tr>
  <% @objects[:events].count.times do |times| %>
      <td class="col1" colspan="1"><%= @input ? text_field_tag("feelings[]#{count}[][name]", @objects[:feelings][count][times].name) : label_tag('feelings', @objects[:feelings][count][times].name) %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% @objects[:events].count.times do |times| %>
      <td class="col2" colspan="1"><%= @input ? text_field_tag("questions[]#{count}[][name]", @objects[:questions][count][times].name) : label_tag('questions', @objects[:questions][count][times].name) %></td>
  <% end %>
  <td class="col3" colspan="4"><%= @input ? text_field_tag('events[][name]', @objects[:events][count].name) : label_tag('events', @objects[:events][count].name) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you want each value as array...right?

Comment: Feelings, Questions, Events = {5 columns, 5 column, 1 column} x 5 rows . i want feelings to come in a nested array [[1st row],[2nd row],[3rd row]...] same for questions. events will simply be [1st row, 2nd row, 3rd row ...]